# Extract forex data from xlm with php and simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$url = "http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
?>
```

This script really works and the output is here:

http://sitoxte.com/test%20mercato/array.php

But what I want to do is put this data to MySQL tabs, I need some help because I want to store the data each minute.

So i Try:

json-to-mysql

but I think that array in xml variable is not adeguate.

I want create a for cicle

and create 69 table like this:

```
  table 1 eur/usd 
id -  Bid - Ask - High - Low - Direction - Last - timestamp
1
2
3
4...
and so on
```

refresh mode is simple and I do in this way whit javascript:

```
    <script>
setInterval(function () {}, 3000);
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},10000);
function myTimer() 
{
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    location.reload();
}
    </script>
```

connetion is simple too and is like this:

```
//Host: 
$localhost="******";
//database
 $mioblog=*******;
//Nome utente: 
$username=********;
//Password: 
$password=*******;
// connessione a MySQL con l'estensione MySQLi
$mysqli = new mysqli("$localhost", "$username", "$password", $mioblog);
// verifica dell'avvenuta connessione
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
// notifica in caso di errore
echo "Errore in connessione al DBMS: ".mysqli_connect_error();
// interruzione delle esecuzioni i caso di errore
exit();
}
else 
{
// notifica in caso di connessione attiva
echo "Connessione avvenuta con successo";
}
```

Comment: Consider adding detail about what you've already tried, and why it's not working for you. It looks as though you're actually asking how you get this script to run once per minute?

Comment: I want only manipolate the xml variable and send a query to msql.

Comment: You will find full cover information here http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php any concrete question please be more specific.

Comment: How I can manipulate $xml array? take only one  currency and variable related to this currency.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you're using for your database, but assuming PDO, something like the below. If you need more details then look up a MySQL tutorial, but hopefully this gets you started and shows you how to traverse the XML.

```
foreach($xml->Rate as $rate) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO tblrate (time, symbol, bid) VALUES (NOW(), :symbol, :bid)";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $query->execute(array(
        ':symbol' => $rate->@attributes['Symbol'],
        ':bid'    => $rate->Bid;
    ));
}
```

edit: If you only need one currency, something like this should work

```
foreach($xml->Rate as $rate) {
    if($rate->@attributes['Symbol'] == 'EURUSD') {
        $query = "INSERT INTO tblrate (time, bid) VALUES (NOW(), :bid)";
        $query = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $query->execute(array(
            ':bid'    => $rate->Bid;
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend Biagio help me to write code:

```
foreach($xml->children() as  $xml_child){
$Symbol = $xml_child['Symbol'];
$Bid = $xml_child->Bid;
$Ask = $xml_child->Ask;
$High = $xml_child->High;
$Low = $xml_child->Low;
$Direction = $xml_child->Direction;
$Last = $xml_child->Last;
echo('$Symbol = '.$Symbol.'<br>');
echo('$Bid = '.$Bid.'<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

final code of php scrip that write in mysql tables every second forex data:
...

```
<body id="top">
<!--    <button onclick="myFunction()">Reload page</button> -->
<a id=demo> <a> 
...

            <?php
    echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", time()).'<br>';  
    $html="";
    $url = "http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    //Host: 
    //echo('var_dump(  $xml)<br>');
    //var_dump(  $xml);

    //SimpleXMLElement 
    //Host: 
    $localhost="----";
    //database
     $mioblog=----;
    //Nome utente: 
    $username=-----;
    //Password: 
    $password=-----;
    // connessione a MySQL con l'estensione MySQLi
     $mysqli = new mysqli("$localhost", "$username", "$password", $mioblog);
    // verifica dell'avvenuta connessione
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
               // notifica in caso di errore
            echo "Errore in connessione al DBMS: ".mysqli_connect_error();
               // interruzione delle esecuzioni i caso di errore
            exit();
    }
    else {
           // notifica in caso di connessione attiva
        //    echo "Connessione avvenuta con successo";
    }
    // sql to create table

    // sql to create table

    foreach($xml->children() as  $xml_child){

    $Symbol = $xml_child['Symbol'];
    $Bid = $xml_child->Bid;
    $Ask = $xml_child->Ask;
    $High = $xml_child->High;
    $Low = $xml_child->Low;
    $Direction = $xml_child->Direction;
    $Last = $xml_child->Last;
    // sql to create table

    /*
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $Symbol (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Bid VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Ask VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    High VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Low VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Direction VARCHAR(30),
    Last VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";*/

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $Symbol (Bid,Ask,High,Low,Direction,Last)
            VALUES ('$Bid','$Ask',$High,$Low,$Direction,'$Last')";
    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     //   echo "Inserito in table ".$Symbol." / bid=".$Bid." / ask=".$Ask."/ High=".$High."/ Low=".$Low."/ Direction=".$Direction."/ Last=".$Last."<br>";

    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $mysqli->error;
    }


    // echo('$Symbol = '.$Symbol.'<br>');
    //echo('$Bid = '.$Bid.'<br>');
    //echo('$Ask = '.$Ask.'<br>');
    //echo('$High = '.$High.'<br>');
    //echo('$Low = '.$Low.'<br>');
    // echo('$Direction = '.$Direction.'<br>');
    // echo('$Last = '.$Last.'<br>');


    }
    $mysqli-->close();

    ?>

....
```